# Merging [app] and [application] tags

Tags: support, tags

Both [app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app) and [application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) tags are used for the same purpose, one being just the short version of the other. Thus, they should be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been completed.

All questions with the [app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app) tag have now been converted to the [application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) tag and a synonym has been created.